# Algo software architecture

Tags: algorithm, architecture, algorithmic-trading

I have the components of a trading robot. This follows the architecture of:

1. Data layer - streaming and formatting data
2. Model layer - updates model and writes events to event queue
3. Intelligence layer - fetch event, classify (buy, sell, null), filter, construct order (instrument, buy/sell, stop), write to order queue
4. Order layer - fetch event, choose size (or reject), place order, write order to DB

My question is:

- What is the best design pattern to co-ordinate all components involved in each layer?

For a (simplified) example, I do not feel the following would be good practice:

1. Model **M** creates an instance of DataSource **D**
2. **M** creates an instance of Intelligence **I**
3. **I** creates an instance of Order **O**

The main point of the above being everything instantiates everything else, so nothing is operating independently (thus reduced redundancy).

But I also don't feel like one class which instantiates everything and manages the interactions is good practice.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why people use IoC, it solves this problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Look at your language/framework stack, and search for an IoC library, it will likely fix most of your issues.

Comment: It looks like this is the best answer I'll get. However it did lead me onto the path I needed, showing me a service locator design pattern and from that a library I can use. Thank you.